All pre-provisioned OneDrive sites are broken - Something went wrong [object Object]
We are dealing with an issue where all pre-provisioned OneDrive sites seem to be broken (not fully provisioned).

We pre-provisioned approximately 500 OneDrive sites and we'll have 500 more by the end of the day. Nearly 3000 OneDrive sites will be pre-provisioned by the end of this month. All of the pre-provisioned OneDrive sites seem to have an issue:

There are only two Links on the home page < user Name > and "Our files".
The Our files tab is broken and shows the Something went wrong [object Object] message.

This is the code that is used to pre-provision OneDrive sites:
Connect-SPOService -url https://redacted-admin.sharepoint.com
Request-SPOPersonalSite -UserEmails joe.doe@redacted.com

We contacted the Microsoft support, but so far, the only workaround they suggested is to ask each user to sign in using this special URL:
https://redacted-my.sharepoint.com?login_hint=joe.do@redacted.com

The domain and the user name need to be changed accordingly. When the users sign in using this special URL, their OneDrive site gets fixed, which is great. However, we have nearly 3000 users and asking each to complete this action is not an option.
Question
Does anyone know how the pre-provisioned OneDrive sites can be fixed using PowerShell or otherwise, without asking all 3000 users to fix it for us?

Wow. Have never seen this, but obviously Microsoft has. What happens if you ask them for a global solution? It might be something on their end that you cannot influence.
And I agree that asking 3000 users to do something is not a solution.
What if you delete the pre-provisioned ODB site and pre-provision it again? Make sure you delete it from the recycle bin as well. Give it a few moments before pre-provisioning. 24h "breathing time" :)
